# ASP.NET Login roles?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I need to secure my website without using the ASP.NET built in login controls or the Forms Authentication.
Its need to support "normal" users and admin users.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's impossible to build anything in ASP.NET without a  tag = )

I can't tell exactly what you are asking, so I will try to go over the whole groundwork.

**ASP.NET Provides Different Authentication Models**

- You can use ASP.NET's built in authentication with [Membership and Roles](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)
- You can write your own ASP.NET membership model
- You can use another ASP.NET authentication model, such as Shibboleth, Windows/IIS, and others, see JD's post.
- You can skip all of these and use your own "authentication", perhaps it is stored as a simple Session variable

**ASP.NET Provides Different Controls**

- There is a handly Login control that integrated with ASP.NET's built in membership making things very easy.
- If you don't want to use that, you can simply use ASP TextBoxes, Buttons, etc, and basically create your own login form.

Answer (score 1):

In adition to JD's and rlb.usa's posts you can also use opemid or windowslive id authentication perhaps. both of these have membership providers for asp.net. Checkout [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com) for those; however if you want a truly customazieable solution perhaps its best for you as rlb.usa pointed out a simple session variable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to use Windows Authentication (rather than Forms Authentication) with ASP.NET? You should choose Windows authentication if your user accounts are maintained by a domain controller or within Active Directory and there are no firewall issues. I think this is what you are after. Here's [a decent write up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998358.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Umm, a quick response is for you to checkout Authentication features provided by IIS.  These include Kerbros, NTLM, Basic Auth, just to name a few.

Comment: Any way to do this without messing with IIS?

Comment: Keberos, NTLM, Basic Auth all are non-IIS approaches.